# Convert number into amount of space

Tags: javascript, math, ascii

I have a number and want it to generate to a string with corresponding space

For Example:

```
var NumberOfSpace = 3;

// This will result in a string with 3 empty space
// the result will be "   "
var space = convertToSpace(NumberOfSpace);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise option:

```
function convertToSpace(n) {
  return new Array(n + 1).join(' ')
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use the [`String.prototype.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method:

```
" ".repeat(3);
```

<sub>[A polyfill for older browsers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat#Polyfill)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `convertToSpace` function

```
var convertToSpace = function (spaces) {
  var string = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
    string += " ";
  }
  return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [**`Array#fill`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and [**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

> *The `fill()` method fills all the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a `static value`.*
>
> *The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to **reduce it to a single value**.*

```js
var NumberOfSpace = 3;

function convertToSpace(param) {
  return new Array(param).fill(' ').reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
}
var space = convertToSpace(NumberOfSpace);
console.log(space);
```

Comment: This is pretty an overkill. Too many method calls for a simple task.

Comment: @Vohuman – Totally agree with you.. I am not sure why `Array#join` did not come in my mind... ;( Thanks for your comment by the way ;)